# Replace xml tag with latest using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say i have following xml

```
<root>
   <subroot1>
      <tag1>value1</tag1>
      <tag2>value1</tag2>
      <tag3>value1</tag3>
      <tag1>value2</tag1>
   </subroot1>
   <subroot2>
      <tag4>value1</tag4>
      <tag3>value2</tag3>
   </subroot2>
</root>
```

i need a xslt(xslt1.0) that removes duplicate tags and only keep the last one they can be in different parents
expected output xml would be this:

```
<newroot>
   <tag2>value1</tag2>
   <tag1>value2</tag1>
   <tag4>value1</tag4>
   <tag3>value2</tag3>
</newroot>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a key and Muenchian grouping, only to identify the last instead of the first duplicate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="*[not(*)]" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <newroot>
          <xsl:copy-of select="//*[not(*)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', name())[last()])]"/>
      </newroot>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEG